# Why use FQDN as DNS-server option in DHCP?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, hosts, fqdn, dhcp-option

I've seen multiple default configurations of DHCP-servers with a FQDN set as the DNS-server option. Doesn't this imply a catch-22, or the need for that DNS-server to be in the hosts file of every single client?

example from dhcp3-server in debian 6:
`option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;`

I can see how using a dns name is convenient because it's only an A-record to change, and they can be load balanced if wanted, but I don't see how the client is going to resolve the name.

Why are people using FQDN's as DNS-server addresses in DHCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server should resolve the name then sent the resultant IP to the client.

Comment: Ofcourse! Why didn't I think of that?